# Backup Derby DB Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, backup, derby, database-backups

I wanted to write a groovy script preferably which when called will backup my database in the online procedure. I have found examples on how to do this in java but was confused with groovy script. Any Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

NVM. I just created a java program and followed the instructions on http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/cadminhubbkup01.html